# Obtener datos de dataframe en una lista de listas

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un `dataframe` con diferentes columnas, `nombre`, `cantidad`,`batería`. El cual puede tener una forma parecida a la siguiente.

```
data = [['dev1', 20, '65'],
        ['dev1', 4, '99'],
        ['dev2', 22, '67'],
        ['dev1', 6, '99'],
        ['dev3', 20, '85']
        ['dev3', 35, '33']
]
columnas = ['nombre', 'cantidad', 'bateria']

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columnas)
```

Lo que yo pretendo es obtener el valor final para cada elemento, en este caso reconocido por su nombre. Es decir, para el ejemplo anterior necesito una salida que fuera.

```
lista= [[dev2,22,67],[dev1,6,99],[dev3,35,33]]
```

Por lo tanto yo hago:

```
# Obtengo los diferentes elementos que contiene la columna nombre
elems = list(set(df['nombre']))
# Últimos valores de cada nodo
lista, values = [], []
for el in elems:
    ndf = df.loc[df['Node name'] == el]

    values.append(ndf['nombre'].iloc[-1])
    values.append(ndf['cantidad'].iloc[-1])
    values.append(ndf['bateria'].iloc[-1])

    lista.append(values)
```

Pero lo que me queda es `['dev2',22,67,'dev1',6,99,'dev3',35,33]` ¿Cómo hago para que me quede de la otra manera?

¿Hay alguna manera más eficiente de hacer este proceso de obtención de datos? Imagino que `pandas` nos permite hacerlo más rápido y mejor.

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes usar el método `groupby()` y `tail()` así:

```
df.groupby("nombre").tail(1)

    nombre  cantidad    bateria
2   dev2    22          67
3   dev1    6           99
5   dev3    35          33
```

Y añadiendo `.values.tolist()` se obtiene la lista (sugerido por @abulafia), si no te sirve el resultado como DataFrame:

```
df.groupby("nombre").tail(1).values.tolist()
```

Comment: Y si añades al final `.values.tolist()` ya sale tal como lo pedia el usuario

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Aunque esta es funcional, al final implementé la respuesta de @gustavovelascoh y sugerencia de @abulafia. Más corta y simple con los resultados deseados.**

Al final mi solución fue inicializar la lista `values` dentro del bucle para que se resetee en cada iteración.

```
# Obtengo los diferentes elementos que contiene la columna nombre
elems = list(set(df['nombre']))
# Últimos valores de cada nodo
lista = []
for el in elems:
    values = []
    ndf = df.loc[df['Node name'] == el]

    values.append(ndf['nombre'].iloc[-1])
    values.append(ndf['cantidad'].iloc[-1])
    values.append(ndf['bateria'].iloc[-1])

    lista.append(values)
```

Comment: La solución propuesta por @gustavovelascoh es más breve y eficiente, y puedes combnarla con lo que le puse en un comentario para tener el resultado como lista de listas en vez de dataframe